# Why does col-* not work on my wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using wordpress and bootstrap 3.4.1

When I

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">First</div>
        <div class="col-3">Second</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the out put is

```
first 
second
```

instead of

```
first    second
```

When I do col-md-3 however it does work. I don' understand whats happening?

my functions.php looks like this

```
<?php 
   function enqueue_cafe_kraken_theme(){

       //style
       wp_enqueue_style( 
           "style",
           get_template_directory_uri(  ) ."/style.css",
           array(),
           rand(1,999),
           "all"
       );

       //bootstrap css
       wp_enqueue_style( 
           "bootstrap",
           get_template_directory_uri(  ) . "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
           array(),
           "4.3.1",
           "all"
       );

       //Jquery 
       wp_enqueue_script( 
           "jquery",
           get_template_directory_uri(  ) . "/js/jquery.js",
           array("jquery"),
           "3.4.1",
           true 
       );

       //bootstrap js
       wp_enqueue_script( 
           "bootstrap",
           get_template_directory_uri(  ) . "/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
           array(),
           "4.3.1",
           true 
       );

   }

   add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_cafe_kraken_theme");
```

If anyone could provide any insight that would be great

Comment: Have you confirmed bootstrap css is loading on the front end?

Comment: `col-*` is BS4 feature. BS3 does not support it. BS3 only has `.col-xs-`, `.col-sm-`, `.col-md-` and `.col-lg-` options.

Comment: You say _"I'm using [...] bootstrap 3.4.1"_ and in your code, you wrote `4.3.1`. Which one is it? @palaѕн is right, though